# how to get all values in for loop angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when I alert this I only get the last value of id. ican't findout where I'm going wrong

```
  $scope.addToList = function (products,qty) {
    if ($scope.order.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.order.length; i++) {
            $scope.Thx=$scope.order[i].id;
            }}};

   alert($scope.Thx);
```

Comment: What do you think `$scope.Thx=$scope.order[i].id;` is doing? Inside the loop it is resetting the value of $scope.Thx on every loop. Thus, when you alert _after_ the loop, it will be the very last value.

Comment: `$scope.Thx` should be an array. Then append values to it with `$scope.Thx.push( ... )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `$scope.Thx` as an array first.

```
$scope.Thx = [];

$scope.addToList = function (products, qty) {
    if ($scope.order.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.order.length; i++) {
            $scope.Thx.push($scope.order[i].id);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This line will overwrite the `$scope.Thx` for each iteration inside the loop.

```
$scope.Thx=$scope.order[i].id;
```

Now there are two ways to get the desired result.
1. If you want the separate alert for each item in the array then:

```
$scope.addToList = function (products,qty) {
if ($scope.order.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.order.length; i++) {
        $scope.Thx=$scope.order[i].id;
        alert($scope.Thx);
        }}};
```

2. If you want single alert for all the items.
declare `$scope.Thx` as an array first.

```
$scope.Thx = [];
$scope.addToList = function (products, qty) {
if ($scope.order.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.order.length; i++) {
        $scope.Thx.push($scope.order[i].id);
    }
}
};
var tempVar="";
for(var i=0; i<$scope.Thx.length;i++)
{
    tempVar += $scope.Thx[0]+"\n";
}
alert(tempVar);
```